# Error C1047 in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I am using the VS 2012, and when I am compiling my project in debug mode, there are no errors. but while trying to compile the project in release mode I get the next error message (Error C1047) :

> fatal error C1047: The object or library file '*file.lib*' was created with an older compiler than other objects; rebuild old objects and libraries

I understood that the older versions of VS has a SP1 install that solves this issue, but can't find a solution to this issue.

Did anybody saw this and knows how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try to "rebuild old objects and libraries"?

Comment: Check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173554%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: these are the steps I did and got the same error.